# Configuration Settings From database for multi-tenancy. Using Castle Windsor + S#arp

Tags: nhibernate, castle-windsor, s#arp-architecture, multi-tenant

I am converting my application to a multi-tenancy application, one of my obstacles is that now I have to store settings for each tenant in the database.

I am currently using the DictionaryAdapter to read the settings from my app config file into a IConfigurationSettings interface.

Because I can have many tenants, I think my configuration settings need to be registered to castle with different keys, ideally the host name as the key.

However, during the time of castle registration I don't have access to the Request object to get my hostname, also my NHibernate initialisation hasn't taken place.

Anyone got any suggustions?

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get the settings for each tenant, then can you not do this after the initialisation of NHibernate for the master database and iterate through the tenants?

Also, do the settings actually need to be loaded at startup? Can they be read when required, which will probably be in response to a request.

Comment: well i thought it would be best to load them up on startup of the application and cache them. Then use IoC to get my IConfigurationSettings instance in a base controller.

Comment: The problem I a have with adding them after initialising the database is that I don't have an instance of IWindsorContainer to use...My castle init is done in Application_Start(), whereas my NHibernate init is done in Application_BeginRequest()

Comment: instead of loading the settings at startup, can you load them when required and then cache them?

Comment: yes, but how do i add them to my IoC container then? or are you saying i dont need to?

Comment: Register a single implementation of IConfigurationSettings that would hold the settings for all tenants, you access the settings with something like GetSettingsFor(string key)

Comment: ah ok, i added a IDicionary<string, TenantSettings>() property to my IConfigurationSettings, this contains a dictinoary of all the settings with the domain as the key...does this sound ok?